# Python set {} is not equal to set([]), why?

Tags: python, set

I am doing a few simple experiments with Python sets.
I noticed this strange (to me at least) behavior.

```
>>> {1,2,3} == set([1,2,3])
True
>>> {1} == set([1])
True
>>> {} == set([])
False
>>>
```

Why is the last one saying `False`?
I find it rather illogical.

Is there any good reason for this?

Comment: Well whether the reason is "good" or not is a matter of opinion, but one might say the reason is "pragmatic" because dictionaries are more commonly used than sets. :)

Answer (score 8):

`{}` creates an empty *dictionary*, not a set.

There is no empty set literal, just use `set()` (no arguments).

From the [official Python tutorial on sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

> Curly braces or the `set()` function can be used to create sets. Note: to create an empty set you have to use `set()`, not `{}`; the latter creates an empty dictionary, a data structure that we discuss in the next section.

and from the [*set displays* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#set-displays) of the expressions reference documentation:

> An empty set cannot be constructed with `{}`; this literal constructs an empty dictionary.

Sets are a relatively late addition to the language; using `{elem1, elem2}` to create a set was only introduced in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#new-syntax) and added to Python 2 in [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.7.html#other-language-changes), but `{}` was used for empty dictionaries for, far, far longer, at least as early as 0.9.2 (released 1991).

Comment: Thanks... Now I see ... The following one returns True so all is good, I guess ` {x for x in []} == set([])`

Comment: @peter.petrov: there is no need to pass in an empty list, just use `set()`.